# How to JSOUP parse html following the nextSibling?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup, nextsibling

Have HTML:

```
   <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td width="27%" align="left" valign="top">
    <span class="param">Text0</span> 23<br />
    <span class="param">Text1</span> 173<br />
    <span class="param">Text2</span> 54<br />
    <span class="param">Text3</span> 2<br /><br />
    </td>
    <td width="27%" align="left" valign="top">
    <span class="param">Text4</span><br />
    one <br />
    two <br />
    three <br />
    </td>
    <td width="46%" align="left" valign="top">
    <span class="param">Text5</span><br /> 
    one -<br />
    two -<br />
    three -<br />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I can get value Text0-3 parse code change get(0)-get(3), but cant get Text4 and Text5:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("text.html").get();

Element param = doc.select("span[class=param]").get(0);

Node node = param.nextSibling();

System.out.println(node.toString());
```

How get value Text4 and Text5? get(4) or get(5), now return br, but I need get "one, two, three"

Now i use this code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("text.hml").get();

        Elements params = doc.select("span[class=param]");
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
        Element param = params.get(i);

        Node node = param.nextSibling();

        System.out.println(node.toString());

        }
```

this print:

```
 23
 173
 54
 2
<br>
<br>
```

I need:

```
 23
 173
 54
 2
 one two three
 one two three
```

Crazy code answer:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("text.html").get();

        Elements params = doc.select("span[class=param]");
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        Element param = params.get(i);

        Node node = param.nextSibling();

        System.out.println(node.toString());
        }

        for (i=4; i<5; i++){

            Element apar = params.get(i);

            Node apan = apar.nextSibling();

            System.out.println("apar: "+apan.nextSibling().toString());
            System.out.println("apar: "+apan.nextSibling().nextSibling().nextSibling().toString());
            System.out.println("apar: "+apan.nextSibling().nextSibling().nextSibling().nextSibling().nextSibling().toString());
            //System.out.println(apan.nextSibling().toString());


        }
        for (i=5; i<6; i++){

            Element vih = params.get(i);

            Node vihn = vih.nextSibling();

            System.out.println("vih: "+vihn.nextSibling().toString());
            System.out.println("vih: "+vihn.nextSibling().nextSibling().nextSibling().toString());
            System.out.println("vih: "+vihn.nextSibling().nextSibling().nextSibling().nextSibling().nextSibling().toString());
            //System.out.println(apan.nextSibling().toString());


        }

    }
```

this crazy(?) code prints what I want.

Comment: What does your `node.toString()` print?

Comment: if set: get(0), print 23. If set get(5), print <br>. but I need "one two three"

Comment: Now that you have updated the question, it makes less sense. You initially were looking to get the data within the <span></span> elements. But now you are trying to get random data that has nothing to do with the span elements, but are actual data within the <td> elements. Maybe you can just describe what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `Element param = doc.select("span[class=param]")` you get back a List of elements.
You need to iterate over the list to proces each `<span>` element. 
In your code you are only grabbing one by doing a `Element param = doc.select("span[class=param]").get(0);`

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("text.hml").get(); 
Elements params = doc.select("span[class=param]");
for(Element element: params){
    //Will print out the text contained within the <span>...</span>
    System.out.println(element.ownText());
}

params = doc.select("td");
for(Element element: params){
    //Will print out the text contained in all children nodes of <td> nodes, that are text nodes 
    System.out.println(element.ownText());
    //System.out.println(element.text());
}
```

The above code will print out:

```
Text0
Text1
Text2
Text3
Text4
Text5
23 173 54 2
one two three
one - two - three -
```

This should be enough to get you where you are going. Good Luck!

Comment: if I use each <span> I dont know how to get nextSibling value, Node not work with Elements.

Comment: Document doc = Jsoup.connect("text.hml").get();
   
  Elements params = doc.select("span[class=param]");
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
  Element param = params.get(i);
  
  Node node = param.nextSibling();
  
  System.out.println(node.toString());
       
  }

Comment: I will update the answer with @yar1k comment to make it more readable.

Comment: Yea! Thanks, I update my first Q, construction nextSibling().nextSibling().nextSibling().nextSibling().nextSibling().toString())  normal? I can use more simple code?

Comment: I have updated the answer to show you how to get the text contained with the <span> tags as well as the text in all child text nodes of <td>, which appears to be what you are after.